# uitextview dataDetectorTypes doesn't work with short links like bitly links

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

When UITextView dataDetectorTypes is enabled, all links in the text does look clickable.
But any "short links" like (http://bit.ly/link) are not clickable (even though the UITextView does draw them as links).

Is there any way to add/modify the detection algorithm to make also these links clickable?
(In a way that does not use private APIs and the app can still be submitted to the app store).

Answer (score 2):

The link should be auto-detected and tappable without a problem. Make sure that:

1. Your `UITextView` instance isn't editable
2. Your `UITextView` dataDetectorTypes includes `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`

[image]

[image]